# SQLite seek question

Tags: sqlite, seek

I'm using SQLite version 3 to run the following code.

```
//Run SQL SELCT query
sqlite3_prepare16_v2("SELECT * FROM table_name");
sqlite3_step();

//Need to review results in several iterations
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    //Seek to beginning
    sqlite3_reset();

    do
    {
        //Get values
        sqlite3_column_int();
        ...
        sqlite3_column_text16();
    }
    while(sqlite3_step() == SQLITE_ROW);
}
```

But for some reason the first batch of data I get is all 0's. What am I not doing correct in the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you are showing is pseudocode since you're missing many arguments to the sqlite3 funcitons...

You need a `sqlite3_step` after `sqlite3_reset` and before getting the first row of values.

You can change your `do {`...`} while(sqlite3_step() == SQLITE_ROW)` to a `while(sqlite3_step() == SQLITE_ROW)`...`}` to accomplish that.

This will also eliminate the need to step immediately after the `sqlite3_prepare16_v2`

Comment: Yes, that was a pseudocode. And thanks. It works now. Although it sounds kinda weird to call _step_ after each operation, but we can't judge it from this point...